# Eclipse Android development

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

Eclipse's `Android/layout/main.xml` modifications could not show up while running `MainActivity.java`. Here is code of `MainActivity.java` :

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;

public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = false;

        initialize(new ZBGame(), cfg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.main); //this will set view to your main.xml file.
```

after

`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: Anuradha thanks for response but I have changed my mind to tackle the situation in a different way

Comment: @shani If you can please share that different way :)